# plunker bad request error

Tags: javascript, html, plunker

I want to test my code on plunker. But I am getting error as "bad request" in live preview. I tried debugging but failed. 
here is my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

code link: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/YFwRLfWGBZx9cHtXvm5W?p=preview)

In console I am getting error as "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()"

Anybody has idea about solving this issue?

Comment: please fix the link to your code

Comment: i think your json file is too big, if you just want to check your code try taking a sample of this json file and work with it.

Comment: Yep, the JSON file size is killing it. 395 515 bytes seems to be the maximum that works, at least in the plunker.

Comment: I need that json file...I need to plot map from that json file...what should I do to load such big file?